# Error setting CommandArgument propert in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I was adding my own button to GridView for Delete functionality. However it seems I can't get to set it properly.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
 CommandName="BtnEditDelete" 
  CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empID", "{0}") %>"/> 

Error Shown: Server tag not well formed
    Line 36:
    CommandName="BtnEditDelete" CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
    "empID", "{0}") %>"/>
```

Which property have I set wrongly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
 CommandName="BtnEditDelete" 
  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empID", "{0}") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think CommandArgument is not correctly used. Try if this works.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="BtnEditDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("empID") %>' CausesValidation="false"  Text="Delete" />
```