# Dynamically assigning a value to commandArg of a button in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I'm trying to do this in `Repeater` control where I assign an ID value to the CommandArgs.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>"  style="margin-left:12px"  ID="uplink"   Height="75px" Width="75px" Text="Up" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/uparrow.png" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

However, this format:
`CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>"`

Tells me that the tag is not well formed. I escaped the quotes around the id but that didn't help. How can I assign an int id to CommandArgs to an imagebutton in a Repeater control?  What is the correct format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057589/error-setting-commandargument-propert-in-gridview)  It works.

CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID", "{0}") %>'/>